# window.close() in Mobile Browser not working

Tags: javascript

Is there an alternative way to close current tab  using JS ? because window.close() is not working on Mobile browsers

Comment: i already try window.top.close() and its not also wroking

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, i tried a lot of ways, but none can adapt to all devices.
At last, I use the follow code, I really have no better way.

```
window.opener=null;
window.open('','_self');
window.close();
window.history.go(-1);
$(document.body).hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers will not allow you to close the window using `window.close()` unless the script opened the window. This is a little annoying sometimes. But there is a workaround to resolve this issue.

If you observe the error message that is thrown by Mozilla Firefox, `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by the script`. it clearly says that if the script didn’t open the window, you can’t close that. But we open a blank page in the same window using “_self” as the target window and close the same window. In that way, the script opens the window (which is a blank one) and closes the window too.

So, to put this in the code:

```
<script>
    function closeMe() {
        var win = window.open("","_self"); /* url = "" or "about:blank"; target="_self" */
        win.close();
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<input type="button" name="CloseMe" value="Close Me" onclick="closeMe()" />
```

Ref: [link](https://raghunathgurjar.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/how-close-current-window-tab-in-all-browsers-using-javascript/)

Comment: i already tried that code earlier, but the current browser tab did not close , 
the scenario is I have an ionic App that will open the webpage to signup . the thing is .
if the user is successfully registered  there will be a button that will close the browser

Comment: have you found any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Not a viable solution