# how to close onsen ui application on exit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onsen-ui, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a PWA and I need to close the web application when I click on exit. For the same, I have tried `window.stop()` [referencing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757168/how-to-close-a-progressive-web-app) and then followed by few issues and queries in Onsen library. I tried

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

but that too didn't worked for me.

here is my full code

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
      <v-ons-button @click="closeApp" class="right-btns send-btn mx-fix">
       Exit
     </v-ons-button>
</div>
```

and the closeApp function which I am calling

```
closeApp() {
    this.dialogVisible = false;
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Thank you so much for your help :)