# How to exit a fullscreen webpage (similar to, but no PWA) on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps

I am doing a small experiment to write a simple mobile game as a website. I don't want to overcomplicate the setup. In the end, it's online content, and it should provide a nice experience on smartphones.

I use a simple manifest to allow the application to run in fullscreen mode when added to the home screen and started there (currently, I only worry about Andorid).

manifest.json:

```
    ...
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "orientation": "portrait"
    ...
```

Works like a charm. It's a true fullscreen mode even hiding the lower bar with the "back", "home", "switch apps" buttons. Great immersive experience for a game!

Now, how can I support my user to exit the app? All the OS buttons are gone. I added an "exit" button the the games titles screen. But I fail to implement it.

`exitFullscreen` (and all the other vendor-specific versions) do basically nothing.

`window.close()` does nothing, most likely throws the typical warning that it cannot close windows which haved been opened by the javascript.

`history.back()` is sort of strange, and does not seem to work in the end either. I am doing a SPA with vue-router. So fiddling with the history is a bit difficult for me here. Maybe I am just doing it wrong atm.

Update on that: I confirmed by adding a simple button always calling `history.back()` to all pages of my SPA. When I am at the first page, this button does nothing any more.

Is there a way to implement such an "exit" button?

I have seen: [How to close a progressive web app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47757168/552373)

The difference is, I have a fullscreen app, which makes it not really obvious how to close/exit the app.