# How can I close a PWA App in Angular using hardware back button?

Tags: angular, angular-pwa, angular13

I'm developing a PWA App with Angular, and I've seen that when I install the app and then start using it, if I press the hardware back button it starts to return over the history, but I would like to be able to close all the app when the user is in a specific screen, is it possible?

I'm using Angular 13

Comment: Currently you can get the url for exiting app?

Comment: hello, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583049/close-exit-a-pwa-programmatically

Comment: @WangYinXing I didn't get your idea

Comment: @FelipeRodriguezHerrera it means that isn't possible to close or exit the app whenever I want, close is only possible when the history length is equals to 1, right?