# Angular PWA exiting application with click event

Tags: android, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

How to exit manually in click event from pwa if platform is Android in angular 16?

I tried windows.close and tried to manipulate window.history.length.but as per browser security i think its impossible.

Is there any option to quit from app if its pwa.

Comment: does this answer your question: [Close/exit a PWA programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583049/close-exit-a-pwa-programmatically)